# element gets hidden on giving overflow to x

Tags: html, css

Even though given overflow-y visible when hovering on the child div its getting 10px hidden i want that 10px of the child should be shown.

If i removed both overflow properties its working. Whats the issue happening here how to fix it. I need overflow-x to be hidden

```css
.page-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.offers-parent {
  height: 185px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.offers-child {
  width: 310px;
  height: 185px;
  background: red;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.offers-child:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="offers-parent">
  <div class="offers-child-wrapper">
    <div class="offers-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not clear what the problem is. Can you rephrase your question to make it clearer and perhaps better illustrate what you have versus what you want? Is the 10px you are missing the portion of the `.offers-child` that you can't see when it you move it up using `transform: translateY(-10px);`?

Comment: You have conflicting statements "10px of the child should be shown" and "I need overflow-x to be hidden".  This is like saying I want my blue shirt to be red when I wear a purple jacket.

Comment: Ah, yes. `clip` was added because of the way the two properties conflict: you cannot have `visible` in one axis and `hidden` in the other. `hidden` makes the element a scroll container, which overrides `visible`. `clip` does not create a scroll container, and the world is at peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [overflow-x:clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#clip). It has good support in modern browsers but check with [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow-x%3Aclip) if you need to support something old (like IE11 or Opera mini)

```css
.page-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.offers-parent {
  height: 185px;
  overflow-x: clip;/* changed this from hidden */
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.offers-child {
  width: 310px;
  height: 185px;
  background: red;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.offers-child:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="offers-parent">
  <div class="offers-child-wrapper">
    <div class="offers-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Dev Tip**.

You can use [CSS @supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) to implement `overflow:clip` only where it is supported. Aim for your design to work well enough without it then add the funk on top for supporting browsers.

```
@supports (overflow:clip) {
 /* safe to use overflow:clip */
  .offers-parent {
      overflow-x: clip;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a note about browser support :)

Comment: For browsers which doesn't have support is there any other solution? @moob

Comment: I'm not aware of another solution to your overflow problem but without knowing the design goals I could not say if there is a better approach or not. Fundamentally though you should consider how important and necessary having the effect is. Have a design that looks okay and is not broken on old browsers and then implement any extra behaviours only in browser's that support them. Eg: `@supports (overflow:clip) {/* safe to use clip */}`

Answer (score 0):

You are moving it up so it might be as simple as making the parent large enough to contain that movement.  Here I added some ugly borders and background colors just to show what is where.

```css
.page-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: orange;
  background-color: #FF000020;
}

.offers-parent {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
}

.offers-child {
  width: 310px;
  height: 185px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: solid 1px #ff00ff;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.offers-child:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="offers-parent">
  <div class="offers-child-wrapper">
    <div class="offers-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Alternate with padding on the parent.

```css
.page-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.offers-parent {
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 185px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  background-color: #FF00FF20
}

.offers-child {
  width: 310px;
  height: 185px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.offers-child:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="offers-parent">
    <div class="offers-child-wrapper">
      <div class="offers-child">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```